# Подскажите значение кода

Tags: javascript

В одном из ответов на этом сайте увидел следующую js функцию, суть которой: сфокусироваться на следующем инпуте, при вводе определенного количества символов на предыдущем

```
function testJump(x){
    var ml = ~~x.getAttribute('maxlength');
    if(ml && x.value.length >= ml){
        do{
            x = x.nextSibling;
        }
        while(x && !(/tel/.test(x.type)));
        if(x && /tel/.test(x.type)){
            x.focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите, что означает следующая строка

```
!(/tel/.test(x.type))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это регулярные выражения https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

В данном случае производится проверка совпадения `x.type` с регулярным выражением `/tel/`

```
/tel/.test(x.type)
```

вернет `true` если в строке `x.type` присутствует подстрока "tel"